# Make GMAP api aware that the gmap has been resized

Tags: 7, theming, location, google-maps

I'm using jquery and css to toggle my [gmap](https://drupal.org/project/gmap) between full screen and normal size. However, since the original height is 200px, when I press the full screen button, it only draws 200px of the map and the rest is covered with a gray color. Is there a way to "let the GMap api know" that the map is resized so that it will draw the rest of the map and center the location selected to the new size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regular GMaps API, you would need to reinitialize the map or trigger the resize event to start recalculation/replotting the map.

However, this seems to be a common problem for several users of GMap module and there were no direct answers [1](https://drupal.org/node/781660) [2](https://drupal.org/node/1352802) [3](https://drupal.org/node/672548) [4](https://drupal.org/node/1996466).

This is one of the workarounds:

1. Go to `admin/config/services/gmap` and check `collapsehack`. This feature is supposed to be used when the map is in Drupal's collapsible fieldsets, but what it does is that it triggers map resizing on hash change. You can see this in the source code of `gmap/gmap.js`.
2. In your trigger add any hashchange - such as `#open-map` and `#close-map`.

Here's an example node content. JS/CSS are injected there just to give you an idea:

```
[gmap markers=blue::41.902277040963696,-87.6708984375 |zoom=5 |center=42.94033923363183,-88.857421875 |width=300px |height=200px |control=Small |type=Map]

<p><a id="toggle" href="#open-map">Toggle gmap size</a></p>

<style>
.gmap-control.open {
  width: 640px!important;
  height: 480px!important;
}
</style>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('.gmap-control').hasClass('open')) {
      $(this).attr('href', '#close-map');
    }
    else {
      $(this).attr('href', '#open-map');
    }
    $('.gmap-control').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
</script>
```

I tested this and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: It seems that I spoke too early. The behavior is really strange. It will draw more pixels but not all of them. If I launch firebug, the rest of the pixels will be drawn (same with "Inspect Element" in Chrome). The map center is also lost no matter what. I checked the [corresponding gmap.js code](http://i.imgur.com/mA5vy8S.png) and it seems like it should be working the way you said. I'm missing something pretty obvious here. My custom code looks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/tmhfPg6.png). When I figure this out, I'll propose edits to reflect the solution and accept the answer/award bounty.

Comment: Strange; try changing the height of the map through CSS, rather than jQuery. That's how I did it in the example code and it worked.